# API Request Error (Cross Origin Resource Sharing error)

Tags: spring, ionic-framework, post, request, mixed-content

I uploaded a Spring Boot jar file (Rest API) to my Synology Nas. Now I tried to execute a request from my computer. That worked too. I have an Ionic Angular app that also executes requests (http Request). However, no request goes through in the Ionic app. I get the following message back: CORS error (Cross Origin Resource Sharing error: CorsDisabledScheme). Does anyone know what that means?

UPDATE: I added the following headers:
`.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')  .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true')  .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST','true') .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control')` 
However, now I get the following message: (blocked:mixed-content)

PS: the Site is hosted on Vercel... maybe its something with https.. ?

Comment: `*` cannot be used in conjuction with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: so i have to add a specific origin url? that has to be the url from the server, right?

Comment: Difficult to diagnose the issue without a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example